# Gulp error - "ReferenceError: series is not defined"

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm getting this Reference error on this line:

```
gulp.watch(paths.src.html, series(copyHtml, browserSyncReload));
```

I can't figure out how to fix the problem.  Any suggestions?

**gulpfile.js**

```
// BrowserSync
function browserSync(done) {
    browsersync.init({
        open: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: paths.dist.base
        },
    });
    done();
}

// BrowserSync Reload
function browserSyncReload(done) {
    browsersync.reload();
    done();
}

// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch(paths.src.html, series(copyHtml, browserSyncReload));
    gulp.watch("./tailwind.js", css);
    gulp.watch(paths.src.js, series(minifyJs, browserSyncReload));
}

// Complex tasks
const build = gulp.series(clean, css, minifyCss, minifyJs, purgeCSS);
const watch = gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.build = build;
exports.default = watch;
```

Comment: Either use `gulp.series` or separately include it in your `require` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gulp.series` fixed it:

```
gulp.watch(paths.src.html, gulp.series(copyHtml, browserSyncReload));
```